# Find out huge log statementsusing splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have an existing application where there are multiple application flows in it.

All the flows are of JMS messaging flows - where different system exchanges messages of queue.

I want to find out the huge logger statements from the log - which are like more than 10 lines or so.

**What i tried - I tried using patterns tab where splunk tells us what are repetitive patterns.**

I am good with repetitive patterns - but i want to find out logger statements which are huge  in size.

So - is it possible to find out such log statements which are longer/bigger

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splunk has a built-in field called "linecount" that should do what you want.

```
index=foo
| where linecount > 10
```

You can also find the size of an event using the `len` function.

```
index=foo
| eval size=len(_raw)
| where size > 5000
```

Be aware that Splunk truncates large events to 10,000 characters by default, although that setting can be changed in props.conf via `TRUNCATE = <n>`.